# How can i group by but select only the top 10 under each group by sum?

Tags: mysql, sql, hive

I have what i tihnk is a complicated question... the query below is usally exported into excel:

```
select 
shop_type,
shop_name,
company, 
sum(amount) as amount,
sum(counts) as count, 

from df 

group by shop_type,shop_name,company
```

company is only of two values A, B. The priblem is that when i run the above and throw this into a pivot i am unable to do so because it's so large e.g. 5 million rows.. when i put this into a pivot my rows are shop_type, shop_name (with shop name nested under shop_type) and my columns are company, i then sort by grand total (largest to smallest) whilst also sorting from largest to smallest for each shop_name under shop_type!

How can i run the above but select only the top 10 shop_names u (those with largest share of amount) under each shop_type for both companies (i.e. total)?

Comment: Divide your query to 2 queries, each for separate company (`WHERE company = 'A'` and respectively `= 'B'`). Then join them and obtain final output without pivotting.

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions:

```
select df.*
from (select shop_type, shop_name, company, 
             sum(amount) as amount, sum(counts) as count, 
             row_number() over (partition by company, shop_type order by sum(amount) desc) as seqnum
      from df 
      group by shop_type,s hop_name, company
     ) df
where seqnum <= 10;
```

Note:  Your question is also tagged Hive.  The above is standard SQL, but Hive might be quirky about mixing aggregation and window functions.  If so, you can use one more level of subqueries:

```
select df.*
from (select df.*
             row_number() over (partition by company, shop_type order by sum(amount) desc) as seqnum
      from (select shop_type, shop_name, company, 
                   sum(amount) as amount, sum(counts) as count
            from df 
            group by shop_type,s hop_name, company
           ) df
     ) df
where seqnum <= 10;
```